# Combine Multiple Tables using LEFT JOIN and UNION

Tags: mysql, join

I got **5 different Tables** to get the data. But **first I use 3 tables for testing**. Using **LEFT JOIN** and **UNION**. So far this is the code iv'e been using.

```
SELECT sts.TransferDate as 'Transaction Date', sts.TransNumber as 'Document Number', orderset_details.Quantity as 'Quantity', '' as 'Po Number', '' as 'Sales Invoice', orderset_details.Cost as 'Cost', orderset_details.SerialNumber as 'Serial Number', orderset_details.LotNumber as 'Lot Number', location.Location as 'Location' 
FROM orderset_details 
LEFT JOIN sts ON sts.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId
LEFT JOIN location ON location.LocationId = sts.LocationIdTo  
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '3071' 
UNION 
SELECT drs.OrderDate as 'Transaction Date', drs.TransNumber as 'Document Number', orderset_details.Quantity, drs.PONumber as 'Po Number', '' as 'Sales Invoice', orderset_details.Cost as 'Cost', orderset_details.SerialNumber as 'Serial Number', orderset_details.LotNumber as 'Lot Number', suppliers.Supplier as 'Location' 
FROM orderset_details 
LEFT JOIN drs ON drs.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId 
LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.SupplierId = drs.SupplierId 
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '3071'
UNION 
SELECT stockadjustment.TransactionDate as 'Transaction Date', stockadjustment.TransactionId as 'Document Number', orderset_details.Quantity as 'Quantity', '' as 'Po Number', '' as 'Sales Invoice', orderset_details.Cost as 'Cost', orderset_details.SerialNumber as 'Serial Number', orderset_details.LotNumber as 'Lot Number', location.Location as 'Location' 
FROM orderset_details 
LEFT JOIN stockadjustment ON stockadjustment.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId 
LEFT JOIN location ON location.LocationId = stockadjustment.LocationId 
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '3071' 
Group By orderset_details.ItemId
```

And here is the output.
[image]

The output should be only 1 and that is the last row. My problem is when my 1 or 2 queries is nothing its duplicating some columns which is not right.

How can I only show the data that has been equals to specific ItemId? What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you should use alias only in the first select and you don't have aggregation function so you don't need group by .. because unio return only distinct result

```
SELECT 
    sts.TransferDate as 'Transaction Date'
  , sts.TransNumber as 'Document Number'
  , orderset_details.Quantity as 'Quantity'
  , '' as 'Po Number'
  , '' as 'Sales Invoice'
  , orderset_details.Cost as 'Cost'
  , orderset_details.SerialNumber as 'Serial Number'
  , orderset_details.LotNumber as 'Lot Number'
  , location.Location as 'Location' 
FROM orderset_details 
LEFT JOIN sts ON sts.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId
LEFT JOIN location ON location.LocationId = sts.LocationIdTo  
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '3071' 
UNION 
SELECT 
      drs.OrderDate 
    , drs.TransNumber 
    , orderset_details.Quantity
    , drs.PONumber 
    , ''
    , orderset_details.Cost 
    , orderset_details.SerialNumber 
    , orderset_details.LotNumber 
    , suppliers.Supplier 
FROM orderset_details 
LEFT JOIN drs ON drs.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId 
LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.SupplierId = drs.SupplierId 
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '3071'
UNION 
SELECT 
      stockadjustment.TransactionDate 
    , stockadjustment.TransactionId 
    , orderset_details.Quantity 
    , '' 
    , '' 
    , orderset_details.Cost 
    , orderset_details.SerialNumber 
    , orderset_details.LotNumber 
    , location.Location     
FROM orderset_details 
LEFT JOIN stockadjustment ON stockadjustment.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId 
LEFT JOIN location ON location.LocationId = stockadjustment.LocationId 
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '3071'
```

Comment: Its still the same output :(

Comment: check the select one by one .. and check if the distinct result is correct .. and  why you need a union with 3 select  for select only one row?